# Xcode 4 workspace and scheme's pre-action

Tags: xcode, xcode4, build, workspace

I have a very simple Xcode 4 workspace:

- A simple app : `Foo.app`
- A library : `Bar.a`

As you can imagine `Foo.app` uses `Bar.a`, nothing weird here. When I build `Foo.app` it automatically builds `Bar.a` and that's exactly what I want! But... Because there's always a but... In the build phase of the `Bar.a` scheme, I have a pre-action script.

If I build `Bar.a` the script is executed, but if I build `Foo.app`, Xcode builds automatically `Bar.a` without executing the pre-action script!!!

How can I tell my Xcode friend to execute that script, even when I build `Foo.app`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having tried @joshua's manual declaration of dependency, the only, yet unsatisfying, workaround I found is to add the same script as pre-action of the build of `Foo.app`.

Answer (score 0):

You might try specifying Bar.a as a manual dependency. Edit your scheme and select the Build action. Uncheck "Find Implicit Dependencies" and add the Foo.a target to the Targets list. Drag it above Foo.app so it's built first. I think that might help you - it helps me when dependencies are acting "unexpectedly".

The documentation could be a bit clearer about this (so please do file an enhancement request with Apple).

Comment: Thank you for that idea, but unfortunately it does exactly the same. In fact, the lib is well built, but the pre-action script is not executed. That's really weird.